# How to center navbar items exactly to the center?

Tags: html, navbar, nav, items

Basically my items start at the center, but I want even distribution so the first item starts not in the center but a bit to the left.

Comment: please add sample code as well.

Answer (score 0):

some css should do the job

```
.navbar.center .navbar-inner {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal example I could come up with, https://jsfiddle.net/o8emug03/15/.

Basically, you have to use a `display: flex; justify-content: center;` in your navbar, and append the elements you wish to display inside.